# how to utilise multiple processing in MySQL Workbench in the Server

Tags: mysql, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, multiprocessing

I am currently using MySQL Workbench of AWS to process data. I created my code as stored procedures with parameters so that I can call it to process. The thought of this function is that it sliced the main tables into multiple sub_tables based on the parameters entered and created their own temp tables to process.

Lets say that without splitting the jobs it takes 312sto complete
and when I split it into 7 instances to run simultaneously, it takes 183s for them to complete ( I was expecting to achieve a similar result like 312/7 = 45s around).

I tried to triggered the process through python and manually open multiple connections in MySQL both and they delivered similar results, which was not as good as I thought.

Can anyone help to explain?

Appreciated

Comment: How many cores do you have? Your numbers suggest you have 2. While a single query can only use a single core, if 2 queries uses 2 cores at 100% each, you cannot expect much performance gain by splitting it up into more queries.

Comment: I am running on AWS server which has 16 VCPU, although when I used multiprocessing.cpu_count() in python it returned 2...

Comment: Well, not sure what I can tell you. MySQL and apparently python seem to behave like you have just 2 cores, not sure why (it might be an aws problem, you should add the aws tag or ask a new question about it, probably on serverfault.com). I'd check your utilization graph during executing. Also, on a side note: another resource that is scarce is hdd i/o (which is in most cases the limiting factor for MySQL for big tables, rather than cpu workload), so I'd check this too.

Comment: Thats already very helpful!